# UITableView Layout issue, (Content Inset)

Tags: ios, uitableview

UINavigationController -> UITabBarController -> UIViewController -> UITableView

I have an UINavigationController with an UITabBarController as its rootViewController, Then put an UITableView in one of the tab(UIViewController)

When i switch to one of the tabController which contains an UITableView, The first cell of the tableView under navigation bar. If i push another view controller, then pop back, the tableview relayout right. How to make it layout right on start.

Answer (score 0):

do your layout in *viewWillAppear* can solve the problem

Comment: how to do layout in viewWillAppear
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        .... What here
    }

Comment: set the frame of tableview;or use autolayout(strongly recommand masonry) @Chris

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This is the issue of topLayoutGuide, Fix it (Swift) by override the topLayoutGuide property

```
override var topLayoutGuide:UILayoutSupport {
    get { return (self.parentViewController?.topLayoutGuide)! }
}

override var bottomLayoutGuide:UILayoutSupport {
    get { return (self.parentViewController?.bottomLayoutGuide)! }
}
```

(Objective C)

```
(id<UILayoutSupport>) topLayoutGuide {
return self.parentViewController.topLayoutGuide;
```

}

- (id) bottomLayoutGuide {
  return self.parentViewController.bottomLayoutGuide;
  }
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  //NSLog is required here, just invoke the getter, don't know why in Objective C getter is not invoked by default
  NSLog(@"%@", self.topLayoutGuide);
  }
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
  //NSLog is required here, just invoke the getter, don't know why in Objective C getter is not invoked by default
  NSLog(@"%@", self.topLayoutGuide);
  }